# Vimclojure bracket completion is driving me insane

Tags: clojure, brackets, vimclojure

Hi Folks I'm using vimclojure for all my clojure programming needs.

Vimclojure automatically completes brackets for me and does not let me delete the ones I dont't want.

Here is a quick example:

The code I worte is the following:

```
(defn insert-foo [record]
    (sql/insert-records :test (concat {:id id} record)))
```

Now I see: "I forgot a sql/with-connection" statement here.

I try to insert it before the "sql/insert-records". Now I get this:

```
(defn insert-foo [record]
    (with-connection db) <-- This one I can't delete O.o
        (sql/insert-records :test (concat {:id id} record)))
```

And I can't delete the bracket in vim. It just won't let me. I tried "d,x,...". How can I delete this bracket or wrap an expression in brackets with vimclojure.

Comment: My VimClojure doesn't do that. Could you please post the version of yours, and do a `grep -i vimclojure ~/.vimrc`.

Comment: I totally did not see the paredit plugin installed alongside with vimclojure ... I must have been blind yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I was kind of blind yesterday. I had paredit.vim installed alongside vimclojure wich caused the problem.

Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the case for me too, I was getting insane, I also searched issues for vim-clojure-static. Deleting the paredit.vim folder in my .vim/bundles folder helped :)